# Swift Enum associated values conforming to single protocol

Tags: swift, enums, protocols, associated-types

How can I get associated value of current enum's case as Refreshable not using exhaustive switch?
In condition I only need it retrieved as protocol, which is used for each case associated type.

```
class Type1: Refreshable {}
class Type2: Refreshable {}
class Type3: Refreshable {}

protocol Refreshable {
    func refresh()
}

enum ContentType {
    case content1(Type1 & Refreshable)
    case content2(Type2 & Refreshable)
    case content3(Type3 & Refreshable)
    
    func refreshMe() {
        //self.anyValue.refresh() //Want simple solution to get to the refresh() method not knowing actual current state
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a switch here since each case has its own definition so to speak, there is nothing stopping you from adding a completely different case like `content4(String)` so you can't generalise the handling of the case items and their associated values

Comment: Do you even need an enum here, maybe an array of `Refreshable` could be used instead?

Comment: No, I need enum, exactly as it is in the question.

Comment: Ok but then you also need to use a `switch`

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution where I don't need switch. You can check in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution in case anyone will need this too.

```
enum ContentType {
    case content1(Type1 & Refreshable)
    case content2(Type2 & Refreshable)
    case content3(someLabel: Type3 & Refreshable)
    
    func refreshMe() {
        let caseReflection = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.value
        (caseReflection as? Refreshable)?.refresh() //If associated type doesn't have label
        
        let refreshable = Mirror(reflecting: caseReflection).children.first?.value as? Refreshable
        refreshable?.refresh() //If associated type has label
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, did you forget something? Doing `ContentType.content1(Type1()).refreshMe()` leads to a crash -> _Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_

Comment: Try changing the method to `if let caseReflection = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.value as? Refreshable { caseReflection.refresh() }` and it should work

Comment: Thanks for checking. Really the code I've provided was working only if associated value has label, did not test without. Added a piece of code that works without labels too (if no labels, caseReflection already contains the target object).
Works with both now.